# 4 Level Picklist Dependency

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, controller, dependent-picklist

I'm trying to set up 4 picklist that are dependent on each other.
The idea is this:

There are 4 different picklist.
`Pick1`, `Pick2`, `Pick3`, `Pick4`

`Pick2` is **dependent** on `Pick1`.

`Pick3` isn't necessarily 'dependent' but the value is set by a concatenation of both `Pick1` and `Pick2`.

`Pick4` is dependent on `Pick3`.

The problem is although `Pick3`'s value on the frontend updates, there is no change to `Pick4`'s values. So you'll see `val1-val2` visually showing on the picklist. I did a console log on `Pick3` and found that the concatenation of `Pick1` and `Pick2` wasn't picked up all the way.

`Pick3`'s value should be set to `val1-val2` but the console log is only showing `val1-`. I'm thinking that's why `Pick4`'s values aren't updating.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm>
     <lightning:inputField aura:id="ex1" fieldName="Pick1" conchange="{!c.updateVal}" />
     <lightning:inputField aura:id="ex2" fieldName="Pick2" conchange="{!c.updateVal}" />
     <lightning:inputField aura:id="ex3" fieldName="Pick3" />
     <lightning:inputField aura:id="ex4" fieldName="Pick4" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

controller.js

```
updateVal:function(component, event, helper){
     var p1 = component.find("ex1").get("v.value");
     var p2 = component.find("ex2").get("v.value");
     var p1p2 = p1+ '-' +p2;
     var p3 = component.find("ex3").set("v.value", p1p2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to re-render the 4th dependent picklist after the value for the third picklist was set. I accomplished this using `<aura:if isTrue="">`